# Connect Sonoff and physical switch with a lamp

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I want to connect smart [Sonoff switch](https://www.itead.cc/sonoff-wifi-wireless-switch.html) to lamp with physical on-off switch

I want these all scenarios to work:

1. when physical switch is off, I can turn the lamp on/off via sonoff switch
2. when physical switch is on, I can turn the lamp on/off via sonoff switch
3. when sonoff switch is on, I can turn the lamp off by physical switch

---

Can anyone tell me how to connect it?

[image: sonoff switch]

Comment: Sounds like a 3 way setup is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small lesson in control wiring. All start switches are wired in parallel and all stop switches are wired in series.

In your scenario you have a mechanical switch that can only be wired in either a stop position or start position. Meaning your scenario doesn't physically work.

You might try two smart switches which do not require physical wiring but instead uses electronic logic to turn your load on and off. That would allow you to connect the smart switches in a parallel configuration and each switch operates independently from each other. Much like two 3-way switches which would work also if you are able to rewire the circuit.

Good luck

Comment: can I use a switch with relay?

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do it that way. Your wall switch physically cuts the power off so that means the wifi switch isn't on anymore. What you could do is rewire the switch to remove the physical component (in other words the device would always be hot) and replace it with a compatible wifi switch like [this one](https://www.itead.cc/sonoff-touch.html).

The catch here is you'll almost certainly need a neutral in the light switch box. Make sure you have one or you'll be re-running wire to that box to make this work.